# gh-pages : Do not cache certain images

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I have my build server upload a pass/fail graphic to gh-pages after each build. I want to display it on my project's page.

http://jasperblues.github.io/Typhoon/build-status.png

However, it seems gh-pages is caching. . how can I tell gh-pages not to cache this iamge?

Comment: How about this? `http://jasperblues.github.io/Typhoon/build-status.png?ver=123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a file in the directory where the png image is contained called .htaccess

The contents should be:

```
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 5 minutes"
```